# Looking for an UTF-8 table

Tags: data-request, computing

I'm looking for a csv file containing the utf-8 encoding table.
This file would contain the code point, the escaped html entity and the symbol itself.

I already found websites providing these correspondances, like [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) or [this other one](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl). However, they do not provide an offline access and pasting all the content would be, while technically possible, a little bit tedious.

Would you know where such a file is available ?

Comment: You may want to ask on stackoverflow.com, too.

Comment: The best website for Unicode characters is [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/index.htm)

Comment: Be aware that some Unicode "characters" are "combining marks", which bind with the preceding character to form a grapheme (e.g., an accent that combines with a latin letter)

Comment: If I were you, I would base my work on the official Unicode documents at www.unicode.org, in particular http://www.unicode.org/reports/ and even more in particular the [UnicodeData.txt file](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt)

Comment: Numeric HTML entities are easily built as `&#x<HEX>;`, where `<HEX>` is the Unicode codepoint in hex (the first column of the UnicodeData.txt file, with or without leading zeros)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With python you can lookup each unicode character by its integer code using [unichr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr).

```
import sys
with open('unicode.csv','wb') as output:
    for i in xrange(sys.maxunicode):
        output.write(unicode(i))
        output.write(u',')
        output.write(unichr(i).encode('utf-8'))
        output.write(u',')
        output.write(unichr(i).encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace'))
        output.write(u'\n')
print sys.maxunicode
```

This gives you a file (unicode.csv) which has the unciode integer, unicode representation, unicode character, and HTML escaped character (for non-ascii).

For example, each line looks like this:

```
64058,u'\ufa3a',墨,&#64058;
```

I put the [code](https://gist.github.com/philshem/10251329#file-create_csv_unicode-py) and the [unicode.csv file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/philshem/10251329/raw/7fd3ad59f291e38e95d23d5b98e7114d44775140/unicode.csv) on github for easier access.

**Note:** Because the unicode character set includes newline characters, CSV is not really the best format. (See lines 10 to 13.) I also added a [python code](https://gist.github.com/philshem/10251329#file-create_json_unicode-py) to generate a JSON file, which is more safe than CSV for storing unicode characters.

Comment: The best solution would be to generate the lookup on the fly (my code takes about 1 second, but the load times for CSV and JSON are much longer).